# Express rendering single object route rather than index route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous, routes

I am trying to create an index page for all post objects using Express and am getting this error when I try to render the page:
Cast to ObjectId failed for value "index" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Post"

this is my controller for the route:

```
>! const Post = require('../models/post')
>! 
>! module.exports = {
>! posts index
>! async postIndex(req, res, next) {
>! let posts = await Post.find({});
>! console.log(posts) 
>! res.render('posts/index', { posts });
```

And these are my routes for the all post objects:

```
>! const express = require('express');
>! const router = express.Router();
>! const { asyncerrorHandler } = require('../middleware/index');
>! const { 
>! postIndex, 
>! postNew,
>! postCreate,
>! postShow,
>! postEdit,
>! postUpdate
>! require('../controllers/posts');
>! 
>! GET posts index /posts
>! router.get('/', asyncerrorHandler(postIndex));
>! 
>! GET posts new /posts/new 
>! router.get('/new', postNew);
>! 
>! POST posts create /posts
>! router.post('/', asyncerrorHandler(postCreate));
>! 
>! 
>! GET show /posts/:id
>! router.get('/:id', asyncerrorHandler(postShow));
>! 
>! GET edit /posts/:id/edit
>! router.get('/:id/edit', asyncerrorHandler(postEdit));
>! 
>! PUT update /posts/:id
>! router.put('/:id', postUpdate);
>! 
>! DELETE destory posts/:id
>! router.delete('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
>! res.send('DELETE /posts/:id/delete');
>!   });
>! 
>!
```

It seems like Express is mapping this posts/index route as though it is post/:id route, and I have no idea why it seems to be doing that, instead of showing me a list of post objects.

Comment: Either you try to send a request incorrectly or the problem is in `postShow` function

Comment: Hey @Konard, I realised the error was a my mine, as it worked fine on localhost:3000/posts/ , and that the controller path was just telling it where to look for the template to display, the actual route was not posts/index but posts